# TypeError: title() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>           self.run()
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
>           self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
>           fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
>           self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
>           all_issues = self._run_checks(
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
>           return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
>           new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
>           return check_resolver(resolver)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
>           return check_method()
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
>           for pattern in self.url_patterns:
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in **get**
>           res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
>           patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in **get**
>           res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
>           return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
>         File "", line 783, in exec_module
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\WILLIAMSWEBSITE\TJWEXOTICS\urls.py", line 21, in 
>           path('', include('TJW.urls'))
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
>           urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
>         File "", line 783, in exec_module
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "C:\Users\danfi\PycharmProjects\TJWEXOTICS\WILLIAMSWEBSITE\TJW\urls.py", line 8, in 
>           path('', views.title(), name='home-page'),
>       TypeError: title() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

```
>this is my views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.

def title(request):
    return render(request, 'TJW/Homepage.html')


>and my TJW/url.py:

from django.http import request
from django.urls import path


from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.title(), name='home-page'),
    path('', views.owned(), name='home-page'),

]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you invoke the function instead of passing it as a view.

It should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.title, name='home-page'),
    path('', views.owned, name='home-page'),

]
```